# imagemagick crop large image fail，Some pictures are missing

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have a huge picture with a length of 388800 pixels and a height of 1920 pixels. I want to crop this picture horizontally into multiple small pictures of 1080*1920 pixels.

`convert 1-all.png -crop 1080x1920 +repage -scene 1 doing1/1-%03d.png`

What I got through the above command is only the first 20 pictures, not all 36 pictures

My original picture is as follows
[enter link description here](https://why-1305585395.cos.na-siliconvalley.myqcloud.com/chen/2022-01-06-1-all.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-page your input image **before** you start cropping:

```
magick image.png +repage -crop 1080x1920 +repage -scene 1 DEBUG-%02d.png
```